# Why is this python loop going to infinity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 10
counter = 0
condition = (counter<3)
while condition:
    a= a +1
    print (a)
    counter = counter + 1
```

[imagedescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvN3j.jpg)

Comment: Because `condition` is only evaluated once. If you want to run it every time you have to put it inside the while loop (`while counter < 3:`, or `while condition: condition = (counter < 3)`. In other words, `condition = (counter < 3)` evaluates to `True`, and is equal to writing `condition = True`.

Comment: @Thymen Please don't put answers in the comments; post an answer instead please

Answer (score 7):

Because `condition` is calculated once and never is updated. So, `condition` is always `True` even though `counter` is updated.

Answer (score 6):

In the line

```
condition = (counter<3)
```

Python executes the comparison on the right and assigns it to "condition" on the left. This happens once before the loop and `condition` is always `True`. You seem to be under the impression that `condition` is a function, but it's not. Its right hand side is only run once, before the loop begins.

The easy fix is to do the operation in the loop condition so that it is re-executed every time.

```
a = 10
counter = 0
while counter < 3:
    a= a +1
    print (a)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `condition` never changes inside the loop. You must update your condition inside of the loop looking like this:

```
a = 10
counter = 0
condition = counter < 3
while condition:
    a= a +1
    print (a)
    counter = counter + 1
    condition = counter < 3
```

But this violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. I would completely remove your condition variable and implement your condition with your logic like so:

```
a = 10
counter = 0
while counter < 3:
    a= a +1
    print (a)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initially assigned condition it was given the value 'True'.
Its value doesn't change when you increase counter. A better method would be:

```
a = 10
counter = 0
while counter < 3:
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
    counter = counter + 1
```